# i've been trying to make a python snake game with python but i keep on getting "pygame not initialised" error

Tags: python-3.x, pygame, game-physics, pygame2

I've been trying to make a python snake game with python but I keep on getting "pygame not initialized"

Error :
[image: code]

[image]
[image]

Comment: Please read [Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Do not post screenshots of the code. Paste the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't called pygame.init() anywhere